# How to save an HTML event for later use?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to save the event for later use and then dispatch it at a later date of my choosing.

The event is a simple button click.

Can I do this given the Event object that is returned from an HTML event handler?

My only requirement is that I save the event and then dispatch it at a time in the future.

Stuff like this does not appear to be working:

```
//Here and now.
this.props.savePendingHtmlEvent(cleanEvent);
//There and then.
if (this.props.pendingHtmlEvent !== undefined) {
        return window.dispatchEvent(this.props.pendingHtmlEvent);
        //return event.target.dispatchEvent(evt)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can - just assign a global variable on the click:

```js
var eventObj;

document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", e => eventObj = e);
document.getElementById("print").addEventListener("click", () => console.log(eventObj));
```

```html
<button id="save">Store event object</button>
<button id="print">Show event object</button>
```